Unable to cancel asyncio.task from another function
I was expecting to cancel foo_wrapper using cancel function, however, it still generates result.
If I change foo_wrapper as non-async function and change self.lock to threading.Lock solves the issue. Any idea?
import asyncio
from typing import List, Optional

class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tasks = set()
        self.lock = asyncio.Lock()

    async def foo(self) -> str:
        # Simulate some asynchronous operation
        await asyncio.sleep(2)  
        return "response"
    
    async def foo_wrapper(self) -> str:
        task = asyncio.create_task(self.foo())
        async with self.lock:
            self.tasks.add(task)
        return task

    def cancel(self):
        for task in self.tasks:
            print(f'cancel {task}')
            print(task.cancel())

async def main():
    bar = Bar()
    c = bar.foo_wrapper()
    bar.cancel()
    try:
        print(await (await c))
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print('Canceled 2')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())



The task is added to self.tasks by the coroutine c/foo_wrapper, which doesn't run until after you've tried to call bar.cancel. At the point in time where you call bar.cancel() there are no tasks in self.tasks. So, you're never cancelling your task in this scenario. Only when await c is executed is the task is created and added to self.tasks, so it is never cancelled.
The lock around accessing self.locks is inconsequential. Set objects are already thread-safe, adding to a set doesn't yield back to the event loop, so neither asyncio.Lock or threading.Lock are needed. So, foo_wrapper probably also doesn't need to be async either and your code can be written like so:
class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tasks: set[asyncio.Task] = set()

    async def foo(self) -> str:
        # Simulate some asynchronous operation
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        return "response"

    def foo_wrapper(self) -> asyncio.Task:
        task = asyncio.create_task(self.foo())
        self.tasks.add(task)
        return task

    def cancel(self):
        for task in self.tasks:
            print(f'cancel {task}')
            print(task.cancel())


async def main():
    bar = Bar()
    task = bar.foo_wrapper()
    bar.cancel()

    try:
        print(await task)
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print('Canceled 2')

I suspect that when you switched the implementation to use threading.Lock you also made foo_wrapper synchronous at the same time (which is what actually caused the behavior difference, because it created and added the task to self.tasks immediately).

With bar.foo_wrapper() you're creating coroutine that halts on async with self.lock and never has chance to add task to self.tasks.
You can use loop.call_soon() to schedule cancelling next loop iteration:
import asyncio
from typing import List, Optional


class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tasks = set()
        self.lock = asyncio.Lock()

    async def foo(self) -> str:
        # Simulate some asynchronous operation
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        return "response"

    async def foo_wrapper(self) -> str:
        task = asyncio.create_task(self.foo())
        async with self.lock:
            self.tasks.add(task)
        return task

    def cancel(self):
        for task in self.tasks:
            print(f"cancel {task}")
            print(task.cancel())


async def main():
    bar = Bar()
    c = bar.foo_wrapper()
    asyncio.get_event_loop().call_soon(bar.cancel)  # <-- use loop.call_soon here
    try:
        print(await (await c))
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("Canceled 2")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

Prints:
cancel <Task pending name='Task-2' coro=<Bar.foo() running at /root/app/script.py:196> cb=[Task.task_wakeup()]>
True
Canceled 2


Small nitpick... "coroutine that halts on async with self.lock" isn't quite correct or consequential here. They're not even awaiting the foo_wrapper coroutine, so the async with self.lock is not even particularly consequential. No other function is acquiring the same lock, anyhow. You could remove the lock acquisition entirely from OP's code and the same problem occurs.
